# How To Explain Monterrey Expansion and Hard coded ADA values?

Tags: ada, supply

I have heard the term Monterrey Expansion used to talk about the ADA supply, but my understanding is that the total amount of ADA is fixed.

How can you have a hardcoded value for a upper bound on ADA and have an expanding supply of ADA at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without repeating what's [in the documentation already](https://docs.cardano.org/explore-cardano/monetary-policy) , monetary expansion refers to a percentage of ADA unlocked from reserves to distribute to treasury and stake rewards right before each epoch transition. It does not change the upper bound max-supply of ADA.